# How to change an opened safari browser url from terminal?

Tags: browser, command-line, cmd, terminal, safari

After running the command `open -a safari http://localhost:9090` in terminal, I would like to change the opened safari url to a relative address like `javascript:foo();`, but I couldn't run this url, from the command line, without opening a new safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use applescript for this:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Safari\" to set URL of the front document to \"http://www.google.fr\""
```